# Evaluate :$ \int_0^9 \int_ \sqrt{x} ^3 \frac{x}{y^3}e^{(y^2)}dydx=? $

Tags: integration

> $$ \int_0^9  \int_ \sqrt{x} ^3  \frac{x}{y^3}e^{(y^2)}dydx=?   $$

in here : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E9++%5Cint_+%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D+%5E3++%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7By%5E3%7De%5E%7B(y%5E2)%7Ddydx

answer : 
$$ \int_0^9  \int_ \sqrt{x} ^3  \frac{x}{y^3}e^{(y^2)}dydx=\dfrac{1}{4} (e^9-1)  $$

but i can not please help me !

Comment: My try: wolfram alpha?

Comment: To put some characters in Wolfram Alpha is not considered as a try or as an answer by wise people. What is your honest attempt at the question? What do you get by setting $x=z^2$ then changing the order of integration?

Comment: Sometimes in these types, changing the order of integration works.

Answer (score 2):

By drawing the area you are integrating over, you realise you can change the order of integration and your new boundaries will be : $y$ from $0$ to $3$, and $x$ from $0$ to $y^2$ :
$$ \int_0^3  \int_{0}^{y^2} \frac{x}{y^3}e^{(y^2)}dxdy=\int_0^3    \frac{x^2}{2y^3}e^{(y^2)}\Big|_{x=0}^{y^2}dy=\int_0^3  \ \frac{y}{2}e^{(y^2)}dy$$

Now choose change of variable $u=y^2$ and thus $du=2ydy$. The boundaries will become $0$ to $9$, and you integral will be :
$$\int_0^9 \frac{1}{4}e^{u}du=\frac{1}{4}e^{u}\Big|_{u=0}^9=\frac{e^9-1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Try by  changing the order of integration,
$$\int_{x=0}^9  \left(\int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^3  \frac{xe^{y^2}}{y^3}dy\right)dx=\int_{y=0}^3  \left(\int_{x=?}^{?} \frac{xe^{y^2}}{y^3}dx\right)dy$$

Answer (score 1):

For the solution, you have to use the change of order of integration.

By interchanging $dx$ and $dy$ we have

$$\int_0^9\int_{\sqrt{x}}^3\frac{x}{y^3}e^{y^2}dydx=\int_0^3\int_0^{y^2}\frac{x}{y^3}e^{y^2}dxdy$$
Now after integration you will get the result.